# Can someone identify this unix command?

Tags: linux, unix, diff

At my university, the output from our submitted code is being compared to a correct output using (I think) some unix command. The problem is I don't know what it is or what it means (I don't *think* it's diff)

```
rivers  passed stage A for width  10
rivers  failed stage B for width  10
--- rivers.expF 2013-04-25 18:15:49.093265000 +1000
+++ rivers.outF 2013-04-25 18:15:49.082424000 +1000
@@ -22,4 +22,3 @@
 beyond
 fixing.

-
```

I've got the above output. I imagine that the --- refers to one file, while +++ refers to the other, and 22, 4 is something to do with the line number,  but what does the minus sign at the end mean? ("Beyond fixing" is in the last lines of the input file)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The output you are showing is an "unified diff":
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#Unified_format

It can be generated with `diff -u` but many programs can generate this kind of output.

The minus sign at the end simply indicates that your file is missing a newline compared to the reference file.

Comment: Yep that seems to be spot on. Thank you. Is it right to assume that *my* file is missing that newline and that it's not that I have an additional newline?

Comment: Ah yes you were correct. I printed an additional line and there were no differences. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. Diff tells what has changed from file A to file B. Line starting with a '+' are additions and '-' are deletion. If your file introduces a line deletion from the reference, it means it is missing a new line.

Answer (score 1):

It's trying to install a software patch:

http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_patch.htm

http://linux.die.net/man/1/patch

Comment: A patch, you mean a patch ;)

Comment: I think this looks right. So the output is a set of instructions on how to change my output into the correct output? What does it mean then?

Answer (score 1):

It looks a lot like `diff -Naur`.

Comment: You're absolutely correct: you can create a patch with "diff -Naur": http://linux.die.net/man/1/patch